# SMS permission un-checks itself on API 27 and up

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sms

I have a strange problem on Android API 27 and higher. I have an app for our fire department, that checks every received SMS, and react to it, if the sender is a specified number. (We use SMS alarming, and this app must fire up on each SMS alarm and start doing stuff). Everything works perfectly for android version 26 and below. But for higher versions, the app **stops reading received SMSs after a few hours**. I need to go to apps permissions to **manually** disable and re-enable SMS permission, then it works for a few hours again!! Arrrghhh

I have a BroadcastReceiver class with onReceive function and i have it declared in the Manifest.

The permission is asked with this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS), REQ_SMS_READ)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: Your title is missleading as it has nothing to do with Kotlin..

Comment: OK, thanks for your eddit of the title!

Comment: Please check: https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827

Comment: Hey. I've read this allready, and I've allready submit the Google Play Permissions Declaration Form, to get the permission for my app. But If these restrictions would be the matter here, then I believe my app wouldn't work at all...? I just want the permission to be effective the whole time, and not just for a day.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. It just smells a lot like related to me, but that's it. That's why I commented and did not propose an answer. Good luck, upvoted!